# Create upgrade setup using installshield 2010 primier

Tags: upgrade, installshield

I want to create an upgrade setup. I have an old setup with for example version 1.0.1.43 and my new setup will has version of 1.0.1.45

I have created a new basic MSI project in installshield. I set version to 1.0.1.45 I copied both product code and upgrade code of old setup into upgrade setup. I also added all of new files in setup that should be replaced with files of old setup. I selected all files and then right clicked on them and in properties checked always overwrite option. then in Media section I added a major upgrade with upgrade code of my old setup. then I build the setup.

when I run this setup it shows me that you have installed this application do you want to upgrade it or not? then I choose yes to upgrade. after installing this setup I figured it out that in add/or remove programs version of my application has changed to 1.0.1.45, that means it has been upgraded. but when I check files I see that none of new files has been replaced with new one.

Where am I wrong that this setup ignore all of my new files to replace? I want this setup find old path of old setup and after removing all files, add new files to that path?

thanks

Comment: Examining a verbose log should point out the root cause - what does it say? Also the version change in the last part is relevant for file versions but not relevant for product versions. This can limit your ability to choose between small updates, and minor and major upgrades. Which kind are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying, you have created new MSI installer for upgrade. So in this case the component ID of components in which your files are present, got change. So you need to set values of Component ID with the component IDs of your installer 1.0.1.45. Or you need to create different components with the same target path.
Also you can validate your upgrade build 1.0.1.46 with the main build 1.0.1.45 with following steps.

> Build Menu -> Validate -> Upgrade Validation Wizard

Then give path of your main installer (msi/exe) and your upgrade installer (msi/exe). And check what differences both builds are having.